# SVO triple in case of missing S or V or O?

Tags: phrase-structure, dependency-grammar, svo

hi I'm new to phrase/dependency structure. 
For a project of mine I want to extract from any sentence a meaningful structure with 3 items i.e. triple.

In general case the Subject-Verb-Object is ideal.
The problem is for many sentences some of the items from the triple is missing.

My question is what other element/s of POS/DEP  is suitable to fill in, so I can always have triple (except in the case of 2 word sentences :))

What about sentences which do not have a VERB ?
Is there are part of Linguistics that research those ? Links ?
Can I still generate triplets based on some other structural information ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOOM, which in a cfg is a non-terminal symbol that does not occur on the left-hand side of any phrase structure rule.  Since a cfg does not generate any string containing a non-terminal symbol, once DOOM gets into a phrase structure derivation, it poisons the derivation, which can never lead to generating a grammatical sentence. (A DOOM marking convention was suggested by Paul Postal.)

Comment: what is DOOM, can you provide a link

Comment: I said what it is: a non-terminal symbol of a cfg which occurs on the right side of some phrase structure rule, but never occurs as the left hand side of a phrase structure rule.  How could I be more explicit?  No, I can't provide a link.  Link to me.

Comment: ooo cfg = context free grammar ..... i see, will look it up